# Найти периметр многоугольника

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Задание выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но возможно я что-то не так делаю, не подскажете?

```
from math import *

a = []
while True:
    a.append(int(input()))


len = 0
n = len(a) / 2
print(n)
for i in range(1, n):
    sum = (a[i] - a[i - 1]) ** 2
    len += sum
    i += 1
print(sqrt(l))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```
def len_seg(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return ((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2))**0.5

x = []
y = []
while True:
    try:
        x.append(int(input()))
        y.append(int(input()))
    except EOFError:
        break

x.append(x[0])
y.append(y[0])

perimetr = 0
n = len(x)
for i in range(0, n-1):
    perimetr += len_seg(x[i],y[i],x[i+1],y[i+1])

print(perimetr)
```

Главное - проще работать с `x` и `y` по отдельности. А дальше все просто - ищем длину каждого отрезка и суммируем. Добавив начальную точку еще и в конец массива.

Вы же вообще половину координат не обрабатываете, а те, что обрабатываете - суммируете странное значение `(x-y)**2`...

Comment: Думаю да, но подскажите. Если вводятся значения. Как начинать расчёт. Как программа понимает что все вводные значения введены?

Comment: На каком моменте он начнёт обрабатывать их?

Comment: Когда заканчивается ввод (при перенаправлении из файла - по достижении конца файла, при вводе руками - Ctrl-Z (Windows) или Ctrl-D (Linux) - срабатывает условие `EOFError`, и цикл завершается...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте извлекать квадратный корень из каждого члена суммы. Вы его, кажется, забыли.

Если это не поможет, то рецепт ниже.

Вам, для начала, нужно отсортировать точки по [полярному углу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82#/media/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Polar_coordinates.svg), так как они могут быть заданы в разнобой. А потом, в порядке обхода, против часовой стрелки, например.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Представьте, что одна из точек лежит на оси x (M), другая точка -- P. Полярный угол -- fi. Теперь, пусть M := P. Возьмите следующую точку.

Полный пример :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, Вам нужно перебрать [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7]. Заметим, если в какой-то момент, Вы будете выбирать не такую последовательность, то можете получить, например, в плюс к периметру ещё и [A5, A1].

Для того, чтобы посчитать полярный угол, вы можете воспользоваться [скалярным произведением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). [Здесь](https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=466) есть несколько полезных функций и задач.

Comment: Подозреваю, что Вы усложняете, вряд ли в задаче такого уровня дадут вершины вразнобой

Comment: @MBo если в задаче не сказано иного, то значит в задаче не сказано иного (=.